# SKLearn KernelRidge memory demand

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I am fitting a model with 100,000 samples x 10 features (6 ints and 4 floats), using SKLearn KernelRidge:

```
model = KernelRidge(kernel='linear')
```

Looking at the task manager, 'Python' process takes ~40GB.

Can you please explain why is there such a high demand?
What kind of matrix is built in the background?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather common.  The algorithm for KernelRidge requires a SVD to be performed.  Sadly, the SVD cannot handle a sparse matrix so the _pre_compute_svd function in sklearn just converts the matrix into a dense matrix and moves on.  This tends to blow up memory rather quickly.

You have a couple of choices.  Rewrite the method to handle sparse matrices or just use a different method.  SVR would be the most similiar alternative.

Comment: But my input matrix is not sparse. So how would that help?